# BSOD 0x000000f4(Probably caused by : wininit.exe)

Tags: windows-7, crash, bsod, minidumps

I have `BSOD` with `0x000000f4` code. It appears when system is not loaded at all.
No new hardware where intalled. Only nvidia drivers where updated 3 days ago and they are up to date for now`(version 296.10)`.
System Health Report(perfmon /report) shows nothing interesting(only complained on disabled UAC)
System is on SSD disk(WDC  SSC-D0064SC-2100 B)

[Dump](http://www.mediafire.com/?egzw7rsom5w84ld)

### Spec:

```
OS Name Microsoft Windows 7 Ultimate
Version 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 Build 7601
System Manufacturer Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.
System Model P31-DS3L
System Type x64-based PC
Processor Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU E7200 @ 2.53GHz, 2534 Mhz, 2 Core(s), 2 Logical Processor(s)
BIOS Version/Date Award Software International, Inc. F9, 10.07.2008
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please capture a complete dump because the mini dump strips the module name which caused this. When did this started happening? At what moment did it crash? Does it happen in Safe Mode too?

Comment: Most common causes of f4 bsod, file system corruption, bad sector on hard drive, virus or malware.

Comment: @Moab checked system in viruses vith avast. Nothing found.

Comment: @TomWijsman  it started happening fewdays ago. The computer crashes when nobody is working with it. In nigth. Crashes repeated once in day or once in two days.  Dunno about Safe Mode, need to check.

Comment: @vacuum did you scan it in windows or from a boot cd-usb drive? Some cannot be detected while in windows.

Comment: @Moab nope. Only from windows. I  will check for viruses from bootable usb and check the disk also.

Comment: Use NilSoft BlueScreenView, as it can read the dump files for you and provide you with the information you really need.